# What is a socket link?

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, filesystems

After noticing an interesting environment variable [Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42727/what-is-the-apple-pubsub-socket-render-environment-variable-for). I notice that it was referring directly to this "Render" file.

After doing a listing of "Render":

```
ls -lh Render
```

I see the following output:

```
srwx------ 1 user wheel 0B Mar 5 10:51 Render
```

As referenced in the [ls manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/ls.1.html) it notes this file as a "Socket Link"

What is a socket link?

Comment: Relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket

Comment: Interesting, that's not the sticky bit?

Comment: @MattH The sticky bit indicator would be at the end. This "s" occurs where e.g. "d" would for a directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my understanding, it is a file that can be used to communicate between processes.

Two processes would both open the file and then read and write to it. The data they write to it is received by the reading of the other process.

It is somewhat like a network socket you would use to send data to another PC, just without all the networking.

If you want more technical details see [Unix domain socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)